# App crash when applying show/hide fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I'm trying to apply show/hide fragment. Here is my code:

```
public void loadSpinner() {
    final Fragment specialistPickerFragment = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentAppoinmentDetail);
    kindOfAppoinmentSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.kindOfAppoinment);
    List dataSrc = new ArrayList();
    dataSrc.add("Khám tổng quát");
    dataSrc.add("Khám chuyên khoa");
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MakingAppoinmentActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_config, dataSrc);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_config);
    kindOfAppoinmentSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    kindOfAppoinmentSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (kindOfAppoinmentSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Khám chuyên khoa")) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                        .show(specialistPickerFragment).commit();

            } else {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                        .hide(specialistPickerFragment).commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

I'm using code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347588/show-hide-fragment-in-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). But my app crash when I travel to the activity where I want it to take effect. I did many search on google and they all have same code. Anyone know why?
Here is my error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.hoang.bnhnint, PID: 21150
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:786)
>                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1582)
>                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1565)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1453)

Comment: post error log.

Comment: Make sure you have `R.id.fragmentAppoinment` and `R.id.kindOfAppoinment` set up in your layout

Comment: @Redman it build successfully but crash when using

Comment: @KYL3R if I remove the transaction, everything work well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581127/attempt-to-write-to-field-int-android-app-fragment-mnextanim-on-a-null-object?rq=1